# Better way to manage basic interface states using Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone.js, and I am wondering if there are any common practices for what I'm trying to accomplish. My goal is to manage some basic UI states in my application.

For example, keep track of a menu being opened or closed:

```
(function() {
App.Models.Masthead = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        primaryNavClosed: true
    },

    togglePrimaryNavState: function() {
        this.set('primaryNavClosed', !this.get('primaryNavClosed'));
    }
});

App.Views.Masthead = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#masthead',
    initialize: function() {
        var model = this.model;
        this.primaryNav = this.$('#primary-nav');

        // Close the nav menu when anything outside of the menu is clicked.
        $("body").click(function() {
            model.set('primaryNavClosed', true);
        });
        // Do not close nav menu if the nav menu itself is clicked
        this.primaryNav.click(function() {
            return false;
        });

        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:primaryNavClosed', this.render);
    },

    events: {
        'click #mobile-nav-hamburger': 'togglePrimaryNavState'
    },

    togglePrimaryNavState: function() {
        this.model.togglePrimaryNavState();
        // don't auto close the menu
        return false;
    },

    openPrimaryNav: function() {
        this.model.set('primaryNavClosed', false);
    },

    closePrimaryNav: function() {
        this.model.set('primaryNavClosed', true);
    },

    render: function() {
        if(this.model.get('primaryNavClosed')) {
            this.primaryNav.addClass('closed');
        } else {
            this.primaryNav.removeClass('closed');
        }
        return this;
    }
});
App.masthead = new App.Models.Masthead;
new App.Views.Masthead({ model: App.masthead });
})();
```

HTML for reference:

```
<div id="masthead">
<div class="banner">
    <a href="/"><span>Title</span></a>
</div>
<a href="#" id="mobile-nav-hamburger"></a>
<nav id="primary-nav" class="closed">
    <ul>
        <!-- nav items will go here eventually -->
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

This works as it is, I just get this feeling that I'm going about this in a very poor way. I do appreciate the fact that I can update the data in the model from other parts of my application, and the view will automatically respond accordingly without a lot of grunt work... even for something as simple showing a navigation menu in this case.

Having a hard time finding articles that discuss common patterns for this type of behavior, and would greatly appreciate any thoughts for how this could be improved.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't bother with the model and just store the state directly in the view.

```
(function() {
App.Views.Masthead = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#masthead',
    initialize: function() {
        var view = this;
        this.primaryNavClosed = true;
        this.primaryNav = this.$('#primary-nav');

        // Close the nav menu when anything outside of the menu is clicked.
        $("body").click(function() {
            view.primaryNavClosed = true;
            view.render()
        });

        // Do not close nav menu if the nav menu itself is clicked
        this.primaryNav.click(function() {
            return false;
        });
    },

    events: {
        'click #mobile-nav-hamburger': 'togglePrimaryNavState'
    },

    togglePrimaryNavState: function() {
        this.primaryNavClosed = !this.primaryNavClosed;
        this.render();
    },

    openPrimaryNav: function() {
        this.primaryNavClosed = false;
        this.render()
    },

    closePrimaryNav: function() {
        this.primaryNavClosed = true;
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        if(this.primaryNavClosed) {
            this.primaryNav.addClass('closed');
        } else {
            this.primaryNav.removeClass('closed');
        }
        return this;
    }
});
new App.Views.Masthead();
})();
```

That being said, I don't think you actually need to store the state in your particular case as all the state does is simply determine whether a CSS class is added or removed - why not just make this explicit?

```
(function() {
App.Views.Masthead = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#masthead',
    initialize: function() {
        var view = this;
        this.primaryNav = this.$('#primary-nav');

        // Close the nav menu when anything outside of the menu is clicked.
        $("body").click(function() {
            view.closePrimaryNav();
        });

        // Do not close nav menu if the nav menu itself is clicked
        this.primaryNav.click(function() {
            return false;
        });
    },

    events: {
        'click #mobile-nav-hamburger': 'togglePrimaryNavState'
    },

    togglePrimaryNavState: function() {
        this.primaryNav.toggleClass( 'closed' );
    },

    openPrimaryNav: function() {
        this.primaryNav.removeClass( 'closed' );
    },

    closePrimaryNav: function() {
        this.primaryNav.addClass( 'closed' );
    }
});
new App.Views.Masthead();
})();
```

Comment: Switching to `$("body").click(this.closePrimaryNav)` so that you can `$('body').off('click', this.closePrimaryNav)` in a `remove` override might be a good idea.